# Cx_oracle is cutting year in a date field in some specific cases

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am stuck with next problem when working with dates using python & cx_Oracle.

This one works fine:

```
In [29]: cursor.execute("SELECT TO_DATE('23.09.2015','DD.MM.YYYY') FROM dual")
Out[29]: <cx_Oracle.Cursor on <cx_Oracle.Connection to web@hdb:1521/db11>>

In [30]: cursor.fetchone()
Out[30]: (datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 23, 0, 0),)
```

this works fine also:

```
In [33]: cursor.execute("SELECT sysdate FROM dual")
Out[33]: <cx_Oracle.Cursor on <cx_Oracle.Connection to web@hdb:1521/db11>>

In [34]: cursor.fetchone()
Out[34]: (datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 23, 21, 25, 16),)
```

But when I use oracle `to_date` function with a date field cx_Oracle cuts year value to 2 digits, so instead of `2015` I am getting `15`. Example here:

```
In [31]: cursor.execute("SELECT TO_DATE(TO_DATE('23.09.2015','DD.MM.YYYY'),'DD.MM.YYYY') FROM dual")
Out[31]: <cx_Oracle.Cursor on <cx_Oracle.Connection to web@hdb:1521/db11>>

In [32]: cursor.fetchone()
Out[32]: (datetime.datetime(15, 9, 23, 0, 0),)
```

and here:

```
In [36]: cursor.execute("SELECT TO_DATE(sysdate,'DD.MM.YYYY') FROM dual")
Out[36]: <cx_Oracle.Cursor on <cx_Oracle.Connection to web@hdb:1521/db11>>

In [37]: cursor.fetchone()
Out[37]: (datetime.datetime(15, 9, 23, 0, 0),)
```

There is also a `trunc` function in oracle which could be used for date rounding and it doesn't trigger an issue:

```
In [39]: cursor.execute("SELECT TRUNC(sysdate) FROM dual")
Out[39]: <cx_Oracle.Cursor on <cx_Oracle.Connection to web@hdb:1521/db11>>

In [40]: cursor.fetchone()
Out[40]: (datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 23, 0, 0),)
```

But I suppose my tool to work with user defined DB objects (including views) without any specific restrinctions. Unfortunately this issue wouldn't let me work with dates correctly and currently I can't find any suitable solution.

EDIT. Working example after Rajesh's asnwer:

```
In [104]: cursor.execute("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD.MM.YYYY'")

In [105]: cursor.execute("SELECT TO_DATE(sysdate,'DD.MM.YYYY') FROM dual")
Out[105]: <cx_Oracle.Cursor on <cx_Oracle.Connection to web@hdb:1521/db11>>

In [106]: cursor.fetchone()
Out[106]: (datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 23, 0, 0),)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer to this problem is not using to_date on a date function again.

Your conversion function should be

a) `to_date(string_column,'string_representation')` if you are trying to convert something to a date

or

b) `to_char(date_column,'string_representation')` if you are trying to convert something from a date to a string, typically for reporting, spooling or printing.

If you want to understand the wierd behavior, you can look at your session's NLS settings. When you say TO_DATE(sysdate,...), to_date expects a string, so I think Oracle would try and implicitly convert sysdate to a strng. This happens using NLS_DATE_FORMAT for your current session.

Comment: Cheers! Thank you for your asnwer! I've put working example in the main post

Comment: Hi Oleg - I still don't see why you'd need a to_date for this. in your code, what is your variable "a" defined as?

Comment: Removed variable "a" from the last example so it doesn't confuse anyone, it accidentally derived from my testing. I don't need `to_date` there since I can use `trunc` for date rounding, but I can't guarantee users will avoid it and it's cool I've encountered this behaviour before them. Actually I've always been using `to_date` for date rounding in sql views since I never suspected such aspect

Comment: ok. So, the correct solution would be to use trunc(sysdate) if you want a date output or to_char(sysdate,'string format') if you want to assign/return a string datatype. There isn't a case for to_date(sysdate) either ways. Hope that is clear :)